# Ant ssh can`t connect to computer

Tags: ant, ssh, jsch

I have problem with connection from my ant build.xml via ssh with another computer. I have computer with IP adress: 10.62.11.40, ant i have a ant code to connect with this computer:

```
<available property="ant-jsch.present" file="${ant.home}/lib/ant-jsch.jar"/>
            <fail if="ant-jsch.present" message="Please remove ant-jsch.jar from ANT_HOME/lib see [http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#delegating-classloader]"/>

        <path id="jsch.path">
            <pathelement location="lib/ant-jsch.jar" />
            <pathelement location="lib/jsch-0.1.44.jar" />
        </path>

        <taskdef name="scp" classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.Scp" classpathref="jsch.path" />
        <taskdef name="sshexec" classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SSHExec" classpathref="jsch.path" />

        <echo message="Start Working...123"/>
        <sshexec host="10.62.11.40" username="${username}" password="${password}" command='cmd /C mkdir "C:\\\\newFolder"' trust="true" failonerror="true" verbose="true"/>
```

And it is a piece of output from "ant build.xml" command:

```
  [sshexec] ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
  [sshexec] Permanently added '10.62.11.40' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
  [sshexec] SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
  [sshexec] SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
  [sshexec] SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
  [sshexec] SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
  [sshexec] Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,pa
ssword
  [sshexec] Next authentication method: publickey
  [sshexec] Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive,password
  [sshexec] Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
  [sshexec] Authentications that can continue: password
  [sshexec] Next authentication method: password
  [sshexec] Authentication succeeded (password).
  [sshexec] cmd : cmd /C mkdir "C:\\\\newFolder"
  [sshexec] Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT: 2
fork failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
  [sshexec] Disconnecting from 10.62.11.40 port 22

BUILD FAILED
C:\isNowe\build.xml:11: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\isNowe\lib\macros\lib\is2k8.xml:36: Remote command failed with exit status -1
```

Connection with this computer via normal terminal working properly, I can connect and do something on this computer.

```
'is2k8.xml:36'
```

this line is

```
<sshexec host="10.62.11.40" username="${username}" password="${password}" command='cmd /C mkdir "C:\\\\newFolder"' trust="true" failonerror="true" verbose="true"/>
```

Can you have any idea what`s wrong?

Comment: what is your server?  cygwin-ssh?

Answer (score 0):

You're connecting to the remote host successfully, but the remote command is failing:

```
cmd /C mkdir "C:\\\\newFolder"'
```

Can you run this command successfully from the command line ?

Adding the -d flag to get debug output from Ant may also help.